# C# / LINQ: How to GroupBy when a column's value is not constant

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, group-by

The snippet below shows the method I am using to (try to) pick the "latest" driver of a vehicle when they have the same VIN.  This method is called AFTER I use LINQ to get all transactions for all vehicles at a certain location.  In the

```
group vehicle by new
```

section, **DriverLastName** is the only column that can change from row to row.  The return type of vehiclesGrp is IQueryable

```
var vehiclesGrp = from vehicle in inVehicles
                    group vehicle by new
                                {
                                  vehicle.CCName,
                                  vehicle.DADDivision,
                                  vehicle.DADArea,
                                  vehicle.DADDistrict,
                                  vehicle.DADCity,
                                  vehicle.Vin,
                                  vehicle.CostCenter,
                                  vehicle.GLDivision,
                                  vehicle.VehicleMake,
                                  vehicle.FuelTankCapacity,
                                  vehicle.FuelType,
                                  vehicle.EplanNumber,
                                  vehicle.LicensePlate,
                                  vehicle.DateInService,
                                  vehicle.EstimatedMpg,                                      
                                  vehicle.VehicleStatus,
                                  vehicle.DriverLastName,                                      
                                }
                      into grp
                      select new VehicleDetail
                      {
                        Account = "",
                        ActualMpg = 0,
                        NoteID = 0,
                        NoteCount = 0,
                        CardNum = "",
                        CCName = grp.Key.CCName,
                        CostCenter = grp.Key.CostCenter,
                        DADArea = grp.Key.DADArea,
                        DADCity = grp.Key.DADCity,
                        DADDistrict = grp.Key.DADDistrict,
                        DADDivision = grp.Key.DADDivision,
                        DateInService = grp.Key.DateInService,
                        DriverLastName = grp.Key.DriverLastName,                            
                        EplanNumber = grp.Key.EplanNumber,
                        EstimatedMpg = grp.Key.EstimatedMpg,
                        Exception = "",
                        Exceptions = grp.Sum(vehicle => vehicle.Exception == null ? 0 : 1),
                        ExpenseType = "",
                        FuelGals = grp.Sum(vehicle => vehicle.FuelGals),
                        FuelPin = "",
                        FuelTankCapacity = grp.Key.FuelTankCapacity,
                        FuelType = grp.Key.FuelType,
                        FuelUnitCost = 0,
                        GLDivision = grp.Key.GLDivision,
                        IntAcctPd = 0,
                        InvoiceLineItem = "",
                        LicensePlate = grp.Key.LicensePlate,
                        MaintenanceKey = "",
                        Odometer = grp.Max(vehicle => vehicle.Odometer),
                        OutOfServiceDate = null,
                        SwdsStoreCc = "",
                        TotalAllCost = grp.Sum(vehicle => vehicle.TotalAmount),
                        TotalAmount = 0,
                        TotalFuelCost = grp.Sum(vehicle => vehicle.ExpenseType == "FUEL" ? vehicle.TotalAmount : 0),
                        TotalMaintCost = grp.Sum(vehicle => vehicle.ExpenseType == "MAINT" ? vehicle.TotalAmount : 0),
                        TotalMiscCost = grp.Sum(vehicle => vehicle.ExpenseType == "MISC" ? vehicle.TotalAmount : 0),
                        TransactionDate = grp.Max(vehicle => vehicle.TransactionDate),
                        TranTime = "",
                        TranDay = "",
                        UnitCost = 0,                            
                        VehicleMake = grp.Key.VehicleMake,
                        VehicleStatus = grp.Key.VehicleStatus,
                        VendorAddress = "",
                        VendorCity = "",
                        VendorName = "",
                        VendorState = "",
                        VendorZip = "",
                        Vin = grp.Key.Vin
                      };
  return vehiclesGrp;
```

If driver "Mike" has transactions on the 31st of the month, and driver "John" does not, then Mike should show up as the driver.  If they both show up on the 31st, I don't care which driver, as long as the VIN is not duplicated.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Also, if there is any info I left out, let me know, I'll provide what I can.

Comment: Just a suggestion, try to minimize your problem to only the basic, the city, Mpg ... are irrelevant to the question. We like to help but our time is limited, so when I see something this long I just move on. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Don't group on `DriverLastName` and do `DriverLastName = grp.OrderyBy(v=>v.DriveDate).Last().DriverLastName`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I will keep that in mind for future reference, thanks!

Comment: @juharr, I changed the code to what you suggested, and received the following error message: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'SW.FACTFinder.Shared.ViewModels.VehicleDetail Last (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SW.FACTFinder.Shared.ViewModels.VehicleDetail])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"  I checked somewhere else that said use LastOrDefault, so I tried that, with a similar issue.  Then somewhere else said to use OrderByDescending, then use First/FirstOrDefault, but none of these had any success.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the grouping from what I originally posted to

```
var vehiclesGrp = (from v in inVehicles.AsParallel().AsQueryable()
                  orderby v.TransactionDate descending 
                     group v by new
                                {
                                 v.CCName,
                                 v.SwdsStoreCc,
                                 v.DADDivision,
                                 v.DADArea,
                                 v.DADDistrict,
                                 v.DADCity,
                                 v.Vin,
                                 v.CostCenter,                                     
                                 v.GLDivision,
                                 v.VehicleMake,
                                 v.FuelTankCapacity,
                                 v.FuelType,
                                 v.EplanNumber,
                                 v.LicensePlate,
                                 v.DateInService,
                                 v.EstimatedMpg,                                    
                                 v.VehicleStatus,                                      
                                }
                      into gp
                      let uniqueVinAnyDriver = gp.Max(v => v.DriverLastName)
                      select new VehicleDetail
```

which provided exactly what I needed in terms of returning only the "latest" driver of the vehicle.